# "Time Blocks" with Cron

Tags: shell-script, cron, scheduling

I don't know the technical name for this but I am looking for the following behaviour:

- Define a daily time block (e.g. 9am to 5pm) with an associated action
- If this time block is entered while the computer is on, run the action
- If the computer boots up or resumes from suspend / hibernation, run the action for the current time block (running twice is not a problem).
- Skipped time blocks do not matter

Is this possible to achieve with cron? If not, what tool can achieve this?

To avoid this being an XY problem my aim is that I want to block access to certain sites at certain times (for productivity reasons). I will make a script that updates my host file with different entries depending on the arguments passed. For each time block I want this script to be called with different arguments.

Comment: I'm sure there are much better ways to do this without using cron or the hosts file.

Comment: [8 Website Blockers For Studying, Productivity, & Focus](https://freedom.to/blog/8-website-blockers-for-studying-productivity-focus/)

Comment: If you must use `cron`, simply run your script often, and move the "Am I In the Window of Action?" decision to the beginning of the script. Also read `man anacron`.